# Как рассчитать std при расширении диапазона значений?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,5,3,2,4], 'past_std': [0.0, 0.5, 2.16, 1.92, 1.72, 1.71]})
```

Значения в колонке 'past_std' вычислены вручную, но надо определять это функцией.
Каждое значение - это `std` значений слева, но такой алгоритм.

```
0.0 - это std для [0],
0.5 - это std для [0, 1],
2.16 -это std для [0, 1, 5]
```

и так далее, то есть при расширении диапазона мы пересчитываем `std`.

Как получить во второй колонке значения `std` по такому алгоритму, но функцией?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

решение:

```
df["new"] = df["col"].expanding().std(ddof=0)
```

результат:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
   col  past_std       new
0    0      0.00  0.000000
1    1      0.50  0.500000
2    5      2.16  2.160247
3    3      1.92  1.920286
4    2      1.72  1.720465
5    4      1.71  1.707825
```

PS стоит упомянуть что в Pandas метод `std(ddof=1)` параметр `ddof=1` по умолчанию равен `1`, тогда как в Numpy - `ddof=0`. Поэтому, чтобы получить такие же значения как у вас мне пришлось явно указать `ddof=0`

Comment: Максим, какой же Вы молодец! оперативно и просто)